# PHP way of parsing HTML string

Tags: php, html, rss, simplepie

I have a php string that contains the below HTML I am retrieving from an RSS feed. I am using simple pie and cant find any other way of splitting these two datasets it gets from `<description>`. If anyone knows of a way in simple pie to select children that would be great.

```
<div style="example"><div style="example"><img title="example" alt="example" src="example.jpg"/></div><div style="example">EXAMPLE TEXT</div></div>

to:

$image = '<img title="example" alt="example" src="example.jpg">';
$description = 'EXAMPLE TEXT';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124823/file-get-html-displays-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$received_str = 'Your received html';

$html = str_get_html($received_str);

//Image tag
$img_tag = $html->find("img", 0)->outertext;

//Example Text
$example_text = $html->find('div[style=example]', 0)->last_child()->innertext;
```

See Here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: Just tested "Simple html DOM" and is not reliable on large files. In my case I've gor a file with 2800 divs inside and want to cycle among them but only first 21 occurrences were found....

Answer (score 3):

Try [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
// Create DOM from HTML string
$html = str_get_html('Your HTML here');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Description
$description = $html->find('div[style=example]');
```

Comment: `div[style=example]` matches three nodes.

Answer (score 1):

try using strip_tags:

```
<?php
    $html ='<div style="example"><div style="example"><img title="example" alt="example" src="example.jpg"/></div><div style="example">EXAMPLE TEXT</div></div>';
    $html = strip_tags($html,'<img>');
    // $html == '<img title="example" alt="example" src="example.jpg">'
?>
```