# Getting Fatal error using simple html dom parsing external html

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the latest status (in this case "Shipment delivered in good condidtion") of a TNT parcel but am unable to parse the external html using simple html dom. Getting *Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object on line 6*

```
<?php 
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html('http://www.tnt.com/webtracker/tracking.do?&cons=323626321');

$e=$html->find('table.appTable', 1)->find('tr[valign=top]', 0)->find('td', 3);

echo $e;
?>
```

even the sample code from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm gives me the same error

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
   echo $element->src . '<br>';
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124823/file-get-html-displays-fatal-error

Comment: Do you have file_get_contents blocked on your sever?! Any way please post var_dump($html) for us

Comment: @SoroushFalahati Getting "bool(false)"

what does a blocked "file_get_contents" have to do with "file_get_html"? Do I have to modify something to get it working?

Comment: okay found out that in php.ini the setting allow_url_fopen = Off was blocking file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

```
 file_get_html
```

use

```
 file_get_contents
```

to read html page from url. You need to make sure this function is not blocked. In your case it seems that it was

```
 allow_url_fopen = Off
```

in php.ini which blocked it.

But any way, it is better to use a

```
 if ($html)
```

to become sure everything goes good before doing any thing.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did change allow_url_fopen to Off and it's working properly now.