# simple HTML DOM parser iterate over each node

Tags: php, html, dom

i need some help with the simple HTML DOM parser.
I want to loop through each and every node in the DOM.
I want something similar to the jquery '*'.

Currently my code reads:

```
 $style_array = array();
 foreach($doc1->find('*') as $element)
 {
 array_push($style_array,$element->getAttribute('src'));
 };
 print_r($style_array);
```

This is just an example, im aware that every node will not have an src attribute, but in that case im ready to deal with blank elements in my array. I need it not only for this, but for several other functions that i need to run, iterating over every single node in the document.

At the moment this produces an array with absolutely nothing inside it.

Comment: show how to initiate the $doc1 variable please

Comment: i have that right man, its like :        $doc1 = file_get_html("teststring.html");,, and this is after i;ve done the include as well,, so u dont need to worry about that. @sebas

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7124823/1291428

Comment: @sebas ,, thanks,, please advise,, i have located the problem as being a badly formatted html string, it has some nodes which are not recognized by the php simple dom parser,, in phpquery i was getting errors that said the 'node is not defined',, so i think i have a node that is throwing this stuff into a tizzy,, whats my best solution in such a case.the node is:<g:plusone size="medium" href="http://www.redmondpie.com/iphone-5-and-galaxy-s-iii-tied-in-web-usage-stakes-in-the-us/"></g:plusone>  -- this is what its hanging on.