# file_get_html - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql

I created a script that let you to post a link in a text field, and then upload the picture from the url into MYSQL. The script is working fine in WAMP Server, but when I upload the script to the server, I get the error message:

PHP Warning: file_get_contents(google.com): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /home/CI/CI/Website/Content/Upload/simple_html_dom.php on line 76

PHP code (upload/file_insert.php):

```
include_once "../simple_html_dom.php";

if(isset($_POST['Post'])){
$URL = $_POST['userfile']; //URL from the textarea
$html = file_get_html($URL);
$Element = $html->find('img',0);
$tmpName  = $Element;
$data = $tmpName;
$data = addslashes($data);
$query = "INSERT INTO `tbl_images` ";
$query .= "(image) VALUES ('$data')";
$results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded."; } 
else{ print "No image selected/uploaded"; }
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="Upload/file_insert.php">
<textarea id="text" name="userfile"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Post" name="Post">
</form>
```

simple_html_dom.php is placed correct.

I think there some issue with the file_get_html, but I couldn't find any solution to fix this problem on the internet.

Comment: There isn't enough information here. Can you post the actual PHP error message? It will be logged in /var/log/apache2 if your server is running on apache. Have you connected to the DB with `mysql_connect` somewhere? What makes you think the issue is with file_get_html?

Comment: hint: Try commenting out parts till you reach a working script. There lies your 500er ...  my first guess would be $URL is empty because of a typo in the form. We need the html of the form as well.

Comment: try "$html = file_get_html($URL) or die('this is not a valid url');"

Comment: possible duplicate of [file\_get\_html displays fatal error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124823/file-get-html-displays-fatal-error)

Comment: but the problem there was not including the dom parser .. AH.. is the dom parser where it is supposed to be ?

Comment: Since version 5.2 php creates an HTTP 500 response if there is fatal error and `display_errors` is `off`. So you should check if `display_errors` is `off` on your server and turn it temporary to `on` to find the error faster or check the error logs.

Comment: Fatal error may be caused by $html->find('img',0); as $html has not been created.

Comment: I have now updated with the HTML code and the error messange from the log. I have not included the mysql connect here, but I have remembered it when I try to execute the code, and I have also checked if the mysql connect with the database work.

Comment: Check the `$URL`, sounds invalid `url` supplied.

Comment: @AndyLester if you look at the code, there's `addslashes` being used, so O'Malley will not blow it up and it's not "wide open". Yes, prepared statements would be better, but it's not really fatal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PHP Warning: file_get_contents(google.com): failed to open stream:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in
>   name resolution

This tells that your PHP cannot, fails or is not allowed to connect to internet (dns server) to resolve site google.com. You should contact your service provider to have them clarify why this is so. It's not something you can do anything about in your code (except to try using direct IP, but you should really contact them to have this resolved, as it probably affects elsewhere as well).