# Code works in cpanel but not in Centos web-panel

Tags: php, dom, runtime-error, server

I have simple_html_dom parser script and below is the snippet of code. Now when I run the script in my shared hosting server having cpanel or also my dedicated server having kloxo panel it works fine but when I run it in My dedicated server having Centos Web-Panel, it gives below error.

Error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://example.com/abc/XYZ.html): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/abc/public_html/dom.php on line 75

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/abc/public_html/parse.php on line 29
```

parse.php

```
....
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$url='http://superhdimages.com/results/GJ.html';

include('dom.php');

$html=file_get_html($url);

    $record_find='first';

    foreach($html->find('table#GridView1') as $e){ // Line 29

                 if($record_find=='first')

                 $i=1;

                 foreach($e->find('tr') as $e1){
.....
```

i had browsed through so many questions over stackoverflow and from other forums and googled it, and got so many suggestion like changing some functions in php.ini and etc. but hadn't got succeed. Still have same error. Any help will be appreciable. Please give me some suggestion.

also the php info of my server is here: http://superhdimages.com/info.php

Comment: the path `/home/abc/public_html/dom.php` is different in web-panel.

Comment: means I need to change this line include('dom.php') or anything else, please help me

Comment: I don't know your project structure. I can't help a lot here...

Comment: but this works with cpanel.

Comment: In my opinion the home paths are not the same.

Comment: no, home path are also same for both the server

Comment: what's on line on line 29 in `parse.php`? We can't help without info! We're not fortune tellers...

Comment: foreach($html->find('table#GridView1') as $e){

Comment: does this apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124823/file-get-html-displays-fatal-error ?

Comment: I had tried that but nothing happens