# Loop through <p> tags inside HTML string from database

Tags: php, html, string, loops, parsing

I want to loop through

tags inside HTML string that came from database.

Example:

```
$htmlString = "<p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p>";
```

I want to loop through `$htmlString` variable and get 1, 2, 3 as following:

```
1
2
3
```

I have tried the `simplexml_load_string()` function:

```
$x = "<p>1</p><p>2</p>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);
foreach ($xml->p as $p) {
    {
        echo $p;
    }
}
```

But it gives error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <p>1</p><p>2</p>

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ 

Notice: Trying to get property 'p' of non-object

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: [For HTML.](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Comment: If the HTML is coming from any user source or has any possibility of being irregular or invalid, do not treat it like a string. I'll take the hard line on this and say any answer suggesting you use regex or string functions is incorrect; use DomDocument on HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead, it'll help you parse HTML more easily, here is a sample code:

```
<?php

$string = "<p>1</p><p>2</p>";
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($string);
$paragraphElements = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach ($paragraphElements as $p) {

        var_dump($p->nodeValue);

}
```

Output:

```
string '1' (length=1)
string '2' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

- You need to use [Domdocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).
- I used [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php)'s length attribute to loop through `<p>` tags.

**CODE:**

```
<?php


$dom_document = new DOMDocument();

$dom_document->loadHTML("<p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p>");

$p_tags = $dom_document->getELementsByTagName("p");

for($i=0;$i<$p_tags->length;++$i){
    echo $p_tags->item($i)->nodeValue,"<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Why use length and a for loop when a simple foreach loop will suffice?

Comment: @mega6382 Just another way of doing it. I found this much better to read than foreach magically iterating it because it is `Traversable`.

Answer (score -1):

Why you use simple XML? There is `HTML DOM Parser`:

```
<?php
$x = "<p>1</p><p>2</p>";
$html = str_get_html($x);
$html->find('p');
echo $html; // Outputs 1 and 2
?>
```

Documentation: https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser

Comment: str_get_html() is not defined.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str_get_html()

Comment: You need to include a library : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124823/file-get-html-displays-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function

Answer (score -1):

```
$x = "<p>1</p><p>2</p>";

$values = str_replace(array('<p>', '</p>'), ' ', $x);
$values = explode(' ', $values);

foreach ($values as $val){
    echo($val);
}
```

Comment: This is a bit dangerous, if the structure is invalid or with attributes this will fail. It is not a good idea to parse html with regex or simple string functions.