# How can I use array chunks with different size?

Tags: php, html, arrays, explode

I'm creating a code to make a pagination with explode and array_chunks but I need that in each array has different sizes (I'm inserting paragraphs of an html and each one has different size), how could I do it? Thanks and excuse my English.

```
<?php
$libro = file_get_contents("libro.html");
$parrafosPagina = 3;
if(empty($_GET['p'])){ $pag=1; } else { $pag=$_GET['p']; }
$parrafos = explode('</p>', $libro);
$paginas = array_chunk($parrafos, $parrafosPagina);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have an HTML file that you want to split up by `</p>`, and you want get the elements that would be on the `$_GET['p']`th page?

If that is what you want, would this work for you:

```php
$parrafos = explode('</p>', $libro);

// Page N starts at index (N-1)*(Page Size), assuming N is 1-indexed.
$startIndex = ($pag - 1) * $parrafosPagina;

// This will return an empty array if $startIndex is out of bounds.
return array_slice($parrafos, $startIndex, $paraffosPagina);
```

Otherwise, if you want what `array_chunk()` does, I'm not sure what the purpose of `$_GET['p']` is.  The fact that different paragraphs have different character lengths wouldn't affect anything for this purpose.

Although, if you're trying to get ONLY the `<p></p>` blocks and nothing else from the HTML, instead of using `explode()` I would use `DOMDocument`.  Reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/52990954/13361518

This is because exploding by the paragraph close tag would return much more than just the content of the paragraph tags.

Apologies for not being quite sure what you're asking for, but your question has been idle for a while so I figured I'd give it a go!