# Explode php string on X occurrence of a specific word

Tags: php

How do you select the content of a string based on a changing count?Each time the loop is run the count increments by 1 and the next portion of the string is required.

```
$mystring = 'This is my string. This string is a sample. This is a problem';
```

So if $i==1 then I want

```
echo $newstring // This is my string.
```

At $i==2 I want

```
echo $newstring // This string is a sample.
```

At $i==3 I want

```
   echo $newstring // This is a problem.
```

I have looked at lots of reference pages on explode, substr, array_pop etc but I haven't seen a method that allows for the position of the trigger word to change based on an incrementing counter.

Comment: Iteration usually starts at `0` in PHP. Splitting your input as others have answered is the right way. Also, if your words to split on are all single characters, try `strtok()`.

Comment: You may get better answers if your question had a real example (need this - tried this). Solution might go different way than your assumed algorithm. In you comment below I see that your string comes from html and "the word" is actually a `class` attribute in it. There are parsers for that.

Comment: @shudder The string is actually a db entry for shipping methods. All the html content is superfluous in the application that I'm looking at. I merely want "Free Shipping", Economy Delivery (1Kg) etc from whatever was originally stored, but must be able to get them in a given order.

Answer (score 2):

This could be answered with [Explode a paragraph into sentences in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494176/explode-a-paragraph-into-sentences-in-php)

```
foreach (preg_split('/[.?!]/',$mystring) as $sentence) {
    echo $sentence;
}
```

Also you can access each element:

```
$matches = preg_split('/[.?!]/',$mystring);
echo $matches[0]; // This is my string
echo $matches[1]; // This string is a sample
echo $matches[2]; // This is a problem
```

Comment: Can you explain why your example doesn't work if $mystring  = 'Shipping (<div class="AdvancedShipperShippingMethodCombination"><p class="AdvancedShipperShippingMethod">Free Shipping
<br />1 x IARP IA313200 Door Gasket</p>
<p class="AdvancedShipperShippingMethod">Economy Delivery (1Kg)
<br />1 x WIP69457. Whirlpool Part Number 481946669457</p></div>)';
$chr = 'AdvancedShipperShippingMethod">'; and I change '/[.?!]/' to '/[AdvancedShipperShippingMethod?!]/'
echo $matches gives nothing

Comment: Can you tell me what is the output you want for that string?

Comment: In the example string I would want to find $matches[0]; //Free Shipping and $matches[1]; //Economy Delivery (1Kg)

Comment: Oh ok, then you need to parse it as html, do you think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083076/php-way-of-parsing-html-string) would work?

Answer (score 0):

If `.` is the part where you want to explode the string then you can use regular expression.

```
$line = 'This is my string. This string is a sample. This is a problem.';
preg_match("/([[:alpha:]|\s]+\.)/i", $line, $match);

echo $match[1];
```

Example
https://regex101.com/r/4SHAJj/1

Comment: The string was a pure sample. What if you wanted to explode on a specific word?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Actually regular expression are pretty handy in this kind of things. Just to show you what can we do with regular expression. In this sentences we removed the country codes from the sentences.   https://regex101.com/r/w6HUsQ/1

Comment: It's like black magic to me! I get confused by all the  \ and /, let alone the content within [ ].
If I wanted to search for all occurrences of AdvancedShipperShippingMethod and be able to access them using $match[1], $match[2] etc how would I format the regex?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, and although it may not be the cleanest or best way, it does work. 
 $shippingData contains

```
Shipping (<div class="AdvancedShipperShippingMethodCombination"><p class="AdvancedShipperShippingMethod">Free Shipping <br />1 x IARP IA313200 Door Gasket</p> <p class="AdvancedShipperShippingMethod">Economy Delivery (1Kg) <br />1 x WIP69457. Whirlpool Part Number 481946669457</p></div>)';
```

Code used:

```
$shippingData = $order_result->fields['shipping_method'];
$matches = preg_split("/(AdvancedShipperShippingMethod\">)/", $shippingData);
$method = $matches[$n]; //$n is a count that increments with while/next loop
$method = substr($method, 0, strpos($method, "<br />"));
$method = "Shipping (".$method.")";
}
```